# tmux fzf-tmux freezes when run with shortcut

Tags: ubuntu, zsh, tmux, gnome, fzf

I have a tmux command for switching windows kinda like these guys 
[tmux script for fast window switching with fzf-tmux gives me the wrong options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37730996/tmux-script-for-fast-window-switching-with-fzf-tmux-gives-me-the-wrong-options)

it uses fzf-tmux in it. It worked fine until today when I updated to Ubuntu 20.04. 
The problem is as soon as it gets to fzf-tmux it stops accepting any keyboard input - I can neither close tmux nor switch panes - nothing.

The problem is definitely fzf-tmux: I reduced my command right down to

`bind C-f run-shell "echo 'abc' | fzf-tmux"`

and the result is still the same

If I open second terminal and attach to the same session it works ok until I press the shortcut again.

I tried opening it in different terminal emulator, switching tmux prefix, switching the `C-f` keybinding: the result is still the same.

If I just copy the command and run it in terminal it works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that tmux after 3.0 locks up everything until the run-shell command exits if the -b flag is not passed

https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/issues/1841
https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/2025#issuecomment-567849015